# Uniform initialization in C++ do not works

Tags: c++

when I use [modern json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) in my class, init class member like this:

```
Test::Test(json config) : m_config{config}
{
}
```

it does not work and throws `type::error` exception, but when I do init member like this

```
Test::Test(json config) : m_config(config)
{
}
```

it works, why?

Comment: I'm gonna guess `json{std::initializer_list<json>}` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bit of a look in [the documentation](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json.html). Here's the picture it paints:

```
using   initializer_list_t = std::initializer_list< detail::json_ref< basic_json > >
// helper type for initializer lists of basic_json values
```

Which is of course used to define a constructor:

```
basic_json (initializer_list_t init, bool type_deduction=true, value_t manual_type=value_t::array)
// create a container (array or object) from an initializer list
```

Since the  list initialization causes overload resolution to consider only `std::initializer_list` c'tors first, the above c'tor is matched and called. The source object seems to violate some sort of internal constraint of the `json` class when doing list initialization.

In your other snippet, the copy c'tor is chosen and called.